# Аналог sprintf(s,"%9d",n) в LibreOffice Basic?

Tags: libre-office, basic

Как в LibreOffice Basic для вывода задать (если можно) модификатор ширины поля? (аналог sprintf(s,"%9d",n) в C)

Собственно, имеется такой код:

```
Sub Main

Dim n&, arr&, tmp&, s$

n = InputBox("Введите размерность матрицы")



ReDim arr(1 to n, 1 to n)


for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to n
        tmp = iif(i = j, 2,j)
        arr(i,j) = tmp
    next
next

for i = 1 to n
    for j = 1 to n
        s = s & arr(i,j) & " "
    next
    s = s & chr(13)
next

MsgBox(s)

End Sub
```